# anylogic measure the queuing time of a service block

Tags: optimization, queue, simulation, anylogic, discrete

I have a process flow which has some service blocks. For some reasons, I cannot use separate delays and queue block, I must stick to service block. However, i have some problems when I tried to measure the queuing time only in the service block,

I read some topic in stackoverflow, and follow steps as:

- i clickk into service blockk,
- "on enter" action, i insert the code: `double queueStartTime = time();`
- then "on seize" action, i insert the code `double queueTime = time() - queueStartTime;` 
  and then i create a statistic measure with value equals queue time

it should have worked.

but it said that queueStartTime cannot be resolved to a variable. as this is not answered in last topic, there fore i am seeking for other help.
does anyone get this issue, and you please help.

Answer (score 1):

The "on seize" code box does not know about local variables created in the "on Enter" code box.

Drag a normal AnyLogic variable object `timeEnter` next to the Service block and use that to store the entry time and calculate the time-to-seize.